# spring batch remote chunking for realtime data processing

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

We have to process around 2 million records within 6-7 hrs and all this records are not available immediately. It comes in real time in the batch of 1000 or 2000 like that. I was thinking of using spring batch remote chunking as in our case bottleneck is processing those individual record. Reading them is very fast and also we will not have to read all 2 million all together.

Our goal is to process those 1000 or 2000 records as soon as possible so other system can use it as it is waiting on them.

My question is

1. Is it a good idea to use spring integration jdbc poller to read those 1000 record and launch spring batch job with remote chunking with multiple slave?
2. Is there any sample project available about remote chunking?

Comment: What are you looking to get out of the remote chunking piece of this architecture?

Comment: as we have to process each record individual and it is taking 2-3 sec because it involved external system(WS call), i was thinking having multiple slaves would process each iteam in parallel. Right now we are doing one at a time and it is taking 200 sec for every 100 records. Also this volume might increase in future.